# Shutdown .slideToggle on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

First of all, sorry if my english suck, not my native language and I'll try to do my best :(

So here is my problem. I made a simple menu when you clic on the h2 of the category, you get the sub-category with the .slideToggle.

On mobile, I want them to be all expended when I clic on my burger button and disable the slideToggle.

Here is my html and js so far :

```
<nav class="full">
    <section class="nav">
        <h2>Category 1</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="">Menu 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">Menu 2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">Menu 3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </section>
</nav>
```

and my js is just :

```
var menuAccountBlock = $("section.nav"),
    menuAccountButtonList = $("section.nav > h2"),
    menuAccountList = $("section.nav > ul");

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(menuAccountButtonList).click(function () {
            $(this).parent().toggleClass("active");
            $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
        });

    });
```

So, when I clic on Category 1, it open the ul with slideToggle and add a class for my css. I just want the toggle to be disabled on less than 1020px of windows width, how can I do that ?

Comment: So you don't want slideToggle on the mobile but just show by default or what?

Comment: Exactly. I just want it to be disable and display the ul by default. Actually, it's displayed by default with the css but I can still hide the ul by clicking the h2 and it's what I don't want.

Comment: So check the window dimensions, before you call `slideToggle` …

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a method that detect if your web site run in mobile device (return TRUE or FALSE):**

```
function detectmob() { 
 if( navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)
  || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)  
  || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i) 
  || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i) 
  || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)
  || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)      
  || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)
  ){
    return true;
  }
 else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

**So, you can make a if like this:**

```
if (!detectmob()){//if will not a mobile device
    //here put your code for hide the UL
}
```

> Only if will not run in mobile device will hide the UL.